# making web site responsive

Tags: css, responsive

I am working on this web site: https://www.citysingle.it and I'm trying to make it responsive.

the main problem is that when seen by any device, the page is still wide,
i added this code on the **CSS**

```
body {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
   font-size: 14px; 
  /* font-size: 1em; */
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  color: #333333;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  /* mauro 
    min-width: 80em;*/
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 800px) {
    body {
        min-width: 0;
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
    body {
        min-width: 80em;
    }
}
```

Comment: This most likely means containers inside the body have a larger width definition. You can try to set a max-width for the body and see which element is shrinking incorrectly.

Comment: ok i did from chrome , but seems have no effect

Comment: for what I can see you have some components like the slider/carousel or the form that are going beyond the limits that you are setting in your media queries, you will need to adjust those to work in a more responsive way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this 3 meta tags in your head part of the html

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

The viewport Meta tag alters the behavior of a mobile browser by modifying the "virtual viewport" of the device. The virtual viewport is the view of a mobile device screen that is other than the default view; therefore being deemed "virtual". This allows the screen on devices to have specified zoom behaviors.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```

This Meta tag tells the mobile device to not zoom. This allows the Responsive Template for mobile devices to be loaded in the scripts.